# How to iterate through two unequal in length list in Common Lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp

Im trying to make a function that replaces the values of one list by values of another list if certain conditions are met.

For example, given l1 = ((x 1) (y 2)), l2 = (word x y c) I should get (1 2 c). My approach is to modify l2. I know how to do it with a loop but the loop stops at the shorter list and doesn't keep going.I have tried multiple methods and spent around 6 hours trying to come up with something but cannot.

Below is my code

```
(loop :for x :in (cdr l2):for (a b) in l1
    do(if (eql a x) (nsubst b x l2) ())
    return l2

)
```

It doesn't work for me, and just stop at the first thing so I get like (word *replaced value* c). It even doesn't work when l1 and l2 have the same size

Comment: To add another example, if input l1 = ((a 1 ) (b 2)) l2 = (word a b), I should get (word 1 2) but would only get (word 1 b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SUBLIS

First of all, note that Common Lisp defines a standard function that can be useful when doing term rewriting, namely [`SUBLIS`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sublis.htm):

```
USER> (sublis '((x . 1) (y . 2) (z . 3))
    '(some-tree 
       (with x 
         (and y z 
           (nested (list x y z))))))

(SOME-TREE (WITH 1 (AND 2 3 (NESTED (LIST 1 2 3)))))
```

You can also play with the `:key` and `:test` arguments to cover a lot of use cases.

### Recursive transform

This small comment of yours is however quite important:

> To add another example, if input l1 = ((a 1 ) (b 2)) l2 = (word a b), I should get (word 1 2) but would only get (word 1 b)

As far as I know you have basically two options here:

1. Call your transform function again and again until you reach a fixpoint, ie. there is no further replacement being made. For example you can call `SUBLIS` until the resulting form is `EQUALP` to the input form. Note that this algorithm might not terminate if for example you replace `X` by `Y` and `Y` by `X`.
2. Make a single pass version that use an intermediate `resolve` function, which recursively finds the actual binding of each symbol.

Let's write the second approach because it is simpler to detect circularity in my opinion.

### Resolve a symbol

Given an association list of bindings (the environment), a symbol, let's define `resolve` so that it finds the non-symbol value transitively associated with your symbol:

```
(resolve 'x '((x . a) (y . 0) (a . b) (b . c) (c . y)))
=> 0
```

For example, let's start with a naive recursive function:

```
(defun resolve (value environment)
  (typecase value
    (symbol
     (let ((entry (assoc value environment)))
       (if entry
           (resolve (cdr entry) environment)
           (error "~S is unbound in ~S" value environment))))
    (t value)))
```

Some tests:

```
(resolve 3 nil)
=> 3

(resolve 'x '((x . a) (y . 0) (a . b) (b . c) (c . y)))
=> 0
```

So far so good, but there is a problem if your environment has a circular dependency between symbols:

```
(resolve 'x '((x . y) (y . a) (a . b) (b . c) (c . y)))
=> CONTROL STACK EXHAUSTED
```

Tracing the calls to `resolve` shows that the function calls itself indefinitely:

```
  0: (RESOLVE X ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
    1: (RESOLVE Y ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
      2: (RESOLVE A ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
        3: (RESOLVE B ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
          4: (RESOLVE C ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
            5: (RESOLVE Y ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
              6: (RESOLVE A ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
                7: (RESOLVE B ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
                  8: (RESOLVE C ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
                    9: (RESOLVE Y ((X . Y) (Y . A) (A . B) (B . C) (C . Y)))
                    9: RESOLVE exited non-locally
```

Let's add a `SEEN` parameter that track which symbol has already been seen during our resolution process. I add an auxiliary function `RECURSE` so that I can avoid passing `environment` each time, and keep track of `SEEN`:

```
(defun resolve (value &optional environment)
  (labels ((recurse (value seen)
             (typecase value
               (symbol
                (assert (not (member value seen))
                        ()
                        "Circularity detected: ~s already seen: ~s"
                        value
                        seen)
                (let ((entry (assoc value environment)))
                  (if entry
                      (recurse (cdr entry) (cons value seen))
                      (error "~S is unbound in ~S" value environment))))
               (t value))))
    (recurse value nil)))
```

Some tests:

```
(resolve 3)
=> 3

(resolve 'x '((x . a) (y . 0) (a . b) (b . c) (c . y)))
=> 0

(resolve 'x '((x . y) (y . a) (a . b) (b . c) (c . y)))
=> Circularity detected: Y already seen: (C B A Y X)
```

### Conclusion

Now that you can resolve one symbol, you should be able to resolve multiple symbols in a list (or a tree) of symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You are using two “parallel” iterations in your loop, but you should use two “nested” loops, that is one loop inside the other: the external one to scan trhough `l2`, the inner one to find the right substitution.

```
CL-USER> (defvar l1 (copy-list '((x 1) (y 2))))
L1
CL-USER> (defvar l2 (copy-list '(word x y c)))
L2
CL-USER> (loop for x in (cdr l2)
               do (loop for (a b) in l1
                    when (eql a x)
                    do (nsubst b x l2))
               finally (return l2))
(WORD 1 2 C)
```